# How do I edit the system definition files for quicklisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

I'm trying to install FUF/SURGE on my windows computer, and got stuck on a step.

> Instruct quicklisp where to find the system definition files to load
>   fuf and dependent modules. Create a file in this folder:
>   ~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d with this content:

```
(:source-registry
    (:tree (:home "fuf"))
    :inherit-configuration)
```

I was wondering how do I get to the file listed above and how do i edit it? I have emacs installed with quicklisp/slime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so you need to make these subfolders in your home directory. I'm guessing you installed under windows as I saw your comment on my video! Remember that part of the install was created a home folder and setting it's path in your environment variables.

~ is the symbol for the home directory so you need to create directories for this path ~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d\ which for my setup would be c:\home.config\common-lisp\source-registry.conf.d\

Inside that create directory creare a fuf.conf file and paste the lines from the instructions.

I haven’t got a windows machine to hand but hopefully that's enough to get you going!